# Error message produced when mean(data) is called when mode(data) says "numeric" R

Tags: r, csv

I have a .csv file that I am importing into R in order to do some calculations. What is confusing to me is an error message that I am getting which is as follows:

```
Warning Message:
In mean.default(lace$TOTAL.LACE) :
    argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

The reason I find this odd is because of this:

```
> mode(lace$TOTAL.LACE)
[1] "numeric"
```

So I am utterly confused as to why this is happening.

The data that I am importing looks like this:

```
ENCOUNTER | MRN | AGE | NAME | LACE.DAYS.SCORE | LACE.ACUTE.IP.SCORE | LACE.ER.SCORE | LACE.COMORBID.SCORE | TOTAL.LACE | FAILURE | LOS | DAYS.TO.FAILURE
123       | 123 | 50  | DOE  | 6               | 3                   | 0             | 1                   | 10         | 0       | 0   | 0
```

The LOS column is length of stay and will only be non-zero if the Failure has a 1. Failure is binary 1 or 0. Days.To.Failure will also only be non-zero if Failure is 1.

Here is my code in whole:

```
# Load the requried libraries
library(aod)
library(ggplot2)
library(knitr)

lace <- read.csv("lace for R.csv")
head(lace)
summary(lace)

# This dataset has a binary response called FAILURE. There are four
# predictors of this, Length of Stay, Acute Admission, Comorbidity Score,
# ER visits in the last 6 months. There is also a total.lace coloumn that
# is simply the sum of the four scores

sapply(lace, sd)

# We will no make a two-way contingency table of categorical outcome
#  and predictors we want to make sure there are not 0 cells
xtabs(~FAILURE + TOTAL.LACE, data = lace)

# We now need to convert TOTAL.LACE to a factor to indicate that
# it should be treated as a categorical variable
lace$TOTAL.LACE <- factor(lace$TOTAL.LACE) <-- pos. problem but mode() says numeric

mylogit <- glm(FAILURE ~ TOTAL.LACE, data = lace, family = "binomial")
summary(mylogit)

# We will here use confint to get the confidence intervals of our data
confint(mylogit)
# if there are warnings this will show them
warnings()

# Default confint.default
confint.default(mylogit)

# Wald Test of the TOTAL.LACE (rank)
wald.test(b = coef(mylogit), Sigma = vcov(mylogit), Terms = 2:15)

# Odds Ratios only
exp(coef(mylogit))

# odds ratios and 95% CI
exp(cbind("Odds Ratio" = coef(mylogit), confint(mylogit)))
```

**UPDATE**

I was asked to run dput(lace$TOTAL.LACE) here is sample output:

```
8L, 7L, 5L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 7L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 3L, 
...
.Label = c("3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", 
"11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18"), class = "factor")
```

Also asked to str(lace), here is sample output:

```
'data.frame':   17044 obs. of  12 variables:
 $ ENCOUNTER          : int   ...
 $ MRN                : int   ...
 $ AGE                : int  74 87 74 57 52 60 42 84 75 79 ...
 $ NAME               : Factor w/ 11637 levels "doe",..: 3945...
 $ LACE.DAYS.SCORE    : int  6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 ...
 $ LACE.ACUTE.IP.SCORE: int  3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
 $ LACE.ER.SCORE      : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ LACE.COMORBID.SCORE: int  1 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 2 1 ...
 $ TOTAL.LACE         : Factor w/ 16 levels "3","4","5","6",..: 8 7 9 7 7 7 7 ...
 $ FAILURE            : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ LOS                : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ DAYS.TO.FAILURE    : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
```

Thank You,

Comment: Please show us the output of `dput(lace$TOTAL.LACE)`

Comment: please run `str(lace)`

Comment: Probably, it is not sensible to take a mean of a factor, which is only numeric in the sense that it attaches numeric labels to each category. Try `mean(factor(1))` for the same error.

Comment: ahh ok, I'm very new to R with very insignificant experience I had an idea that the problem was in the conversion but got confused when I ran mode(data)

Comment: Ok your data is not `numeric` but `factor`, cast them back to numerics with `as.numeric(lace$TOTAL.LACE)`

Comment: @statquant where would it make the most sense to put that line? I am assuming at the end of the file where I try to do some new things and it's getting confused

Comment: try `lace$TOTAL.LACE <- as.numeric(lace$TOTAL.LACE)` after `read.csv`

Comment: or look at `?read.csv` for `stringAsFactor=FALSE`

Comment: In this case, `as.numeric(lace$TOTAL.LACE)` will give you numbers 1-16 instead of 3-18.  When converting factors to numbers, you usually need to take the extra step of converting to a character first (ugly, I know): `as.numeric(as.character(lace$TOTAL.LACE))` would do it.

Comment: @statquant its working now, so put as answer so I can accept

Comment: @statquant Wow, don't do that: `as.numeric(as.factor(2))` is 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have red data from a csv, you can tell R to stop casting `string` to `factors` with `stringsAsFactors = F` (see `?read.csv`).
Or you can also simply cast back the factors with `as.numeric`  ie `as.numeric(as.character(lace$TOTAL.LACE))` depending on the data.

Comment: The OP deliberately converts to factor: `lace$TOTAL.LACE <- factor(lace$TOTAL.LACE)` above